# Jquery Toggle Help - Default Hidden

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm using this to toggle the UL after the heading with the class "toggle."

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    })
});
```

With html like this:

```
<h2 class="toggle">Header</h2>
<ul style="display:none">
<li></li>
</ul>
```

I added the display:none to have it be hidden by default until the header is clicked, but I can't seem to get it to open anymore.

Edit: Also, the reason I'm using $(this).next() is because I have multiple headers I want to apply this to on the same page.

Comment: The code is working fine for me, take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agentfitz/DjTJe/

Comment: You're right, the code I had was using a class for the style, and I stupidly had !important next the dispay:none. My bad. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are running jQuery in no conflict mode you need to declare your $ var in your ready function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    })
});
```